# How to configure nginx to enable unix user's location?

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, nginx

I would like to enable personal web account for each unix account of my server.

For exemple, I would like to be able to have `http://IP/user1`, and `http://IP/user2`.

I have tryed this but it doesn't work.

```
server {
  listen 82;
  server_name localhost;
  passenger_enabled off;
  location ~ ^/(.*)$ {
    alias /home/$1/www/;
    index index.php index.htm index.html;
  }

  location ~ .php$ {                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:49232; #this must point to the socket spawn_fcgi is running on.                                                                                                                                               
    fastcgi_index  index.php;                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    /WHAT DOES I ADD HERE??/$fastcgi_script_name;  # same path as above                                                                                                                                
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 }
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full tutorial on how to do it: http://blog.sbf5.com/?p=16

In short though, you should be able to use `$1` if you include that in your php pattern.